# What's the right way to implement a service in a spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using is SpringBoot + JPA.

Java is object-oriented, so it has to manipulate objects, not data.

The method has to be split enough to split.

When implementing the Service end in a Spring Boot, should I hand over an object to **findById**?

Or **findAddrById, findAgeById**... Is this a better way to hand over the prosperties of an object?

1. **findById**

   - The controller requires .getXxx() processing (methods for importing elements of objects) and Null inspection, which results in business logic.
   - Because the method can be broken down sufficiently, the object must be returned completely even if the value of a single professional is required.
2. **findAddrById, findAgeById**

   - Not object-oriented.
   - Data is sent and received, not objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you are asking, but I suspect you are asking what the method signatures your service should return.

Imagine the `Entity` that is stored in your database are of type `User`, I would make the service return `User` objects.

If you need someone's address, you can always just get the `User` object and call `someUser.getAddress()`.

An example

```java
User someUser = userService.getUserById(1);
String address = someUser.getAddress();
int age = someUser.getAge();
```

In any case, the answer to this question is more or less dependant on personal preference.